# how do increment a variable using recursion

Tags: python, json, recursion

My function:

```
def flat(errors: dict) -> dict:
    result = {}
    def inner(errors, key=None):
        if type(errors) is dict:
            for k, v in errors.items():
                inner(v, k)
        elif type(errors) is list:
            for obj in errors:
                inner(obj)
        else:
            result.update({key: errors})
    inner(errors)
    return result
```

json:

```
errors = {
    "last_name": "Имя должно состоять из букв",
    "birth_place": {
        "address": {
            "parts": [
                {
                    "0": {
                        "id": "Неверный идентификатор",
                    },
                },
                {
                    "1": {
                        "id": "Неверный идентификатор",
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
    },
    "groups": [
        {
            "1": "Группа workers не существует",
        },
    ],
}
```

I need such an output:

```
{
    "last_name": "Имя должно состоять из букв",
    "birth_place.address.parts.0.id": "Неверный идентификатор",
    "birth_place.address.parts.1.id": "Неверный идентификатор",
    "groups.1": "Группа workers не существует",
}
```

I get this:

```
{'last_name': 'Имя должно состоять из букв', 'id': 'Неверный идентификатор', '1': 'Группа workers не существует'}
```

How can I increment a string variable with . using recursion? I have problem with recursion mindset

Comment: You need to build the full path for each `key` (i.e. `key + "." + k`) when you call `inner`.

Comment: Concatenating, not incrementing.

Comment: That's also not JSON; it's just an ordinary Python `dict`.

Comment: Thank you, yes I am confused, of cource, concateneting. I mean that the json has already been deserialized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only takes a small change,  You need to past a LIST into `inner`, so you can keep appending the next level's key to that list.  Then just use `join` to make the final key:

```
def flat(errors: dict) -> dict:
    result = {}
    def inner(errors, key=[]):
        if type(errors) is dict:
            for k, v in errors.items():
                inner(v, key+[k])
        elif type(errors) is list:
            for obj in errors:
                inner(obj, key)
        else:
            result.update({'.'.join(key): errors})
    inner(errors)
    return result

print(flat(errors))
```

Output:

```
{'last_name': 'Имя должно состоять из букв', 'birth_place.address.parts.0.id': 'Неверный идентификатор', 'birth_place.address.parts.1.id': 'Неверный идентификатор', 'groups.1': 'Группа workers не существует'}
```

For the record, it is somewhat dangerous to use `key=[]` as a default parameter.  But in this case, since I never modify `key`, it is a safe usage.

Comment: Thank you a lot, everything works :)